# How to avoid nested subscription with logic and side effects

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

Most of the time I am able to avoid nested subscriptions but I'm not sure how to do it with this code:

```
const appleStuff = obtainAppleStuff();
// observeAll returns Observable<Apple[]>
appleService.observeAll().subscribe(apples => {
  let apple = apples.find(this.appleFilter);
  if(!apple){
    apple = appleService.create();
    apple.type = "Red";
    apple.size = 5;
    appleService.update(apple);
    if(apples.length !== 0){
      this.appleService.observeWormsOfApple(apples[0]).subscribe(worms => {
        appleService.linkWorms(worms, apple);
      });
    }
  }
  this.linkAppleStuff(appleStuff, apple);
});
```

Ideally I want to have all side effects either in a tap() or in a single non-nested subscribe(), how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  const appleStuff = obtainAppleStuff();
    appleService
      .observeAll()
      .pipe(
        map(apples => {
          let apple = apples.find(this.appleFilter);
          if (!apple) {
            apple = appleService.create();
            apple.type = "Red";
            apple.size = 5;
          }
          return [apples, apple];
        }),
        tap(([, apple]) => {
          appleService.update(apple);
          this.linkAppleStuff(appleStuff, apple);
        }),
        filter(([apples]) => !!apples.length),
        switchMap(([apples, apple]) => this.appleService.observeWormsOfApple(apples[0]).pipe(withLatestFrom([apple])))
      )
      .subscribe(([worms, apple]) => {
        appleService.linkWorms(worms, apple);
      });
```

Comment: thanks! I'm a little curious how this would work if the linkAppleStuff also had a subscribe in it... would the solution be to rewrite linkAppleStuff so that it returns an observable instead, and then passing the returned observable to the end of the pipe? 
I'm trying to understand how to scale these problems... because it seems to me that even a little change in the logic forces me to substantially change the structure of the pipe.

Comment: yes, you need `linkAppleStuff ` to return an observable and use it at the point that success your logic, ... so instead of using `tap`, you need to use `(switch/merge)Map` to run the inner observable.